# display correct answer javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, radio-button

I am trying to get the following code to display the number of right answers at the end of the timmer any help would be great. also, I am having an issue where the scoreDiv fades away when the timer is up I would like it to appear when the timer is done.

Note: I appoligize for the messy code I am new and trying to learn.

```js
    $(function() {
//-------------Global Var-----------

//lets store our trivia questions in an object
    var trivia = [
                  // question 1
                    {
                        question: "01. What is CSS?",
                        answers: ["Casscading Style Sheets", "Carrot steamed soup", "Corruoted style sheets", "Casscading stairs sheets"],
                        correctAnswer: 0
                    },
                    // question 2
                    {
                        question: "02. Q2?",
                        answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                        correctAnswer: 1
                    },
                    // question 3
                    {
                        question: "03. Q3?",
                        answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                        correctAnswer: 3
                    },
                    // question 4
                    {
                        question: "04. Q4?",
                        answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                        correctAnswer: 3
                    }
                 ];
  
    var timerId;
    var timer      = 10;
    var selections = [];//Holds Selections
    var score      = $('#score');
    var counter    = 0;

    //----------------Create trivia questions in Div---------------
    //start Button  populate
    //Q1
    $("#startButton").on('click', function populate() {
        var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
              testDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>' + trivia[0].question + '</h3>'
                   + '<div> <form> <p> <input type="radio" name ="answer0" value="right">'
                   + trivia[0].answers[0] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer1" value="2">' + trivia[0].answers[1] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer2" value="3">' + trivia[0].answers[2] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer3" value="4">' + trivia[0].answers[3] + '</p>'
                   + '<p></form> </div>';
              var questionsDiv = document.getElementById('questions');
              questionsDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
        }
    });

    //Q2
    $("#startButton").on('click', function populate() {
        var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
              testDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>' + trivia[1].question + '</h3>'
                   + '<div> <form> <p> <input type="radio" name ="answer" value="1">'
                   + trivia[1].answers[0] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="2">' + trivia[1].answers[1] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="3">' + trivia[1].answers[2] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="4">' + trivia[1].answers[3] + '</p>'
                   + '<p></form> </div>';
              var questionsDiv = document.getElementById('questions');
              questionsDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
        }
    });

    //Q3
    $("#startButton").on('click', function populate() {
        var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
              testDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>' + trivia[2].question + '</h3>'
                   + '<div> <form> <p> <input type="radio" name ="answer" value="1">'
                   + trivia[2].answers[0] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="2">' + trivia[2].answers[1] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="3">' + trivia[2].answers[2] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="4">' + trivia[2].answers[3] + '</p>'
                   + '<p></form> </div>';
              var questionsDiv = document.getElementById('questions');
              questionsDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
        }
    });

    //Q4
    $("#startButton").on('click', function populate() {
        var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
              testDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>' + trivia[3].question
                   + '</h3>'+ '<div> <form> <p> <input type="radio" name ="answer" value="1">'
                   + trivia[3].answers[0] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="2">' + trivia[3].answers[1] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="3">' + trivia[3].answers[2] + '</p>'
                   + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="4">' + trivia[3].answers[3] + '</p>'
                   + '<p></form> </div>';
              var questionsDiv = document.getElementById('questions');
              questionsDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
        }
    });
  
    //add radio buttons
    //Come back and loop the populate

    //------------------Start Game-------------------
    //Hide Start Button
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#startButton").click(function(){
            $("#startButton").fadeOut();
        });
    });
      
    //------------------Start Timer-------------------
    $("#startButton").on("click", run);

    function run() {
        timerId = setInterval(decrement, 1000);
    }

    function decrement() {
        timer--;
        $("#show-number").html("<h3>" + timer + "</h3>");

        if (timer === 0) {
            stop();
            alert("times up");
            $('#questions').fadeOut();
        }
    }

    function stop() {

      clearInterval(timerId);
    };

    //-----------------Check awnsers------------------------
    //Pushusers ansers to an array
    function choose() {
        selections[counter] = $("input[type='radio'][name='answer']:checked").val() === "right";
    }
    choose();

    function displayScore() {
        var score = $('<p>',{id: 'score'});

        var numCorrect = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
            if (selections[i] === trivia[0].correctAnswer) {
                numCorrect++;
            }
        }

        score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' questions out of ' + trivia.length + ' right!!!');
        return score;
    }

    displayScore();

    var scoreElement = displayScore();
    score.append(scoreElement).fadeIn();

//-----------------Finish Button------------------------
// when finish button is click skip timer to 0
});
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Poiret One', sans-serif;
 background-color:#8f16cc;
 color: white;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'Poiret One', sans-serif;
 font-size: 4em;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 2em;
}

button {
 color: white;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #8f16cc;
 font-size: 2em;
}

.radio {
 display: block;
}

.answers {
 display: block;
 color: or
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Trivial Game!</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/styles.css">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Trivia Game</h1>
<h2>Test your Knowledge</h2>
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="show-number"></div>

<button id="startButton">Start</button>

<div id="questions">

<div id="score"></div>


</div>

<div id="footer"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>


 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Do you want fadeOut effect?

Comment: several errors
1 is why you are looping again for every question. Just change trivia[0] to trivia[i]evrywhre in first loop and all questions will load
secondly you are using two on click on start button merge them to one as it fires only once

Comment: I tried replacing the trivia[0] to trivia [i] that was my intention when writing the code but for some reason, I cant get it to work so I made a work around it ain't pretty but it works and I will go back and try to fix it later and I will fix the start button issue too. What I would like to do is grab the correctAnswer from the Trivia var and use it to have each question have a correct answer and display in the score div how many they got right at the end of the countdown. (My attempt at this is down at the bottom under Check awnsers in my JS) I hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

**INFO:** Your `#score` div was inside the `#questions` div. When the questions div gets `display:none;` all childs will also be hidden. So I placed the score outside the questions and created a `.hidden` class.

**EDIT:** I replaced the alert() with a console.log() just in case you are wondering ;-).

```js
$(function() {
//-------------Global Var-----------

//lets store our trivia questions in an object
  var trivia = [
  // question 1
    {
        question: "01. What is CSS?",
        answers: ["Casscading Style Sheets", "Carrot steamed soup", "Corruoted style sheets", "Casscading stairs sheets"],
        correctAnswer: 0
    },
    // question 2
    {
        question: "02. Q2?",
        answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
        correctAnswer: 1
    },
    // question 3
    {
        question: "03. Q3?",
        answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
        correctAnswer: 3
    },
    // question 4
    {
        question: "04. Q4?",
        answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
        correctAnswer: 3
    }
];
  
    var timer = 10;
    var timerId;

   var selections = [];//Holds Selections
    var score = $('#score');
    var counter = 0;

//----------------Create trivia questions in Div---------------
//start Button  populate
  //Q1
  $("#startButton").on('click', function populate() {
var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
  testDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>' + trivia[0].question + '</h3>'+ '<div> <form> <p> <input type="radio" name ="answer0" value="right">'
       + trivia[0].answers[0] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer1" value="2">' + trivia[0].answers[1] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer2" value="3">' +trivia[0].answers[2] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer3" value="4">' +trivia[0].answers[3] +'</p>'
       + '<p></form> </div>';
  var questionsDiv = document.getElementById('questions');
  questionsDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
  }
});

  //Q2
  $("#startButton").on('click', function populate() {
var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
  testDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>' + trivia[1].question + '</h3>'+ '<div> <form> <p> <input type="radio" name ="answer" value="1">'
       + trivia[1].answers[0] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="2">' + trivia[1].answers[1] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="3">' +trivia[1].answers[2] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="4">' +trivia[1].answers[3] +'</p>'
       + '<p></form> </div>';
  var questionsDiv = document.getElementById('questions');
  questionsDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
  }
});

  //Q3
  $("#startButton").on('click', function populate() {
var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
  testDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>' + trivia[2].question + '</h3>'+ '<div> <form> <p> <input type="radio" name ="answer" value="1">'
       + trivia[2].answers[0] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="2">' + trivia[2].answers[1] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="3">' +trivia[2].answers[2] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="4">' +trivia[2].answers[3] +'</p>'
       + '<p></form> </div>';
  var questionsDiv = document.getElementById('questions');
  questionsDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
  }
});

  //Q4
  $("#startButton").on('click', function populate() {
var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
  testDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>' + trivia[3].question + '</h3>'+ '<div> <form> <p> <input type="radio" name ="answer" value="1">'
       + trivia[3].answers[0] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="2">' + trivia[3].answers[1] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="3">' +trivia[3].answers[2] +'</p>'
       + '<p><input type="radio" name ="answer" value="4">' +trivia[3].answers[3] +'</p>'
       + '<p></form> </div>';
  var questionsDiv = document.getElementById('questions');
  questionsDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
  }
});

 
  

//add radio buttons
  //Come back and loop the populate

  


  //------------------Start Game-------------------
  //Hide Start Button
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#startButton").click(function(){
        $("#startButton").fadeOut();
    });
});

      
  //------------------Start Timer-------------------
  $("#startButton").on("click", run);

  function run() {
      timerId = setInterval(decrement, 1000);
    }

    function decrement() {
      timer--;
      $("#show-number").html("<h3>" + timer + "</h3>");

      if (timer === 0) {
        stop();
        console.log("times up");
        $('#questions').fadeOut();
        $('#score').removeClass('hidden');

      }
    }

    function stop() {

      clearInterval(timerId);
    };



    

  //-----------------Check awnsers------------------------
  //Pushusers ansers to an array
  function choose() {
   selections[counter] = $("input[type='radio'][name='answer']:checked").val() === "right";
  }
  choose();

  function displayScore() {
    var score = $('<p>',{id: 'score'});
    
    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === trivia[0].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }
    
    score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' questions out of ' +
                 trivia.length + ' right!!!');

    return score;
  }
  displayScore();

  var scoreElement = displayScore();
        score.append(scoreElement).fadeIn();




//-----------------Finish Button------------------------
// when finish button is click skip timer to 0
});
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Poiret One', sans-serif;
 background-color:#8f16cc;
 color: white;
}

.hidden{
  display:none;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'Poiret One', sans-serif;
 font-size: 4em;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 2em;
}

button {
 color: white;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #8f16cc;
 font-size: 2em;
}

.radio {
 display: block;
}

.answers {
 display: block;
 color: or
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Trivial Game!</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/styles.css">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Trivia Game</h1>
<h2>Test your Knowledge</h2>
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="show-number"></div>

<button id="startButton">Start</button>

<div id="questions"></div>

<div id="score" class="hidden"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>


 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this fixed my disappearing div great but what I would like to do is grab the correctAnswer from the Trivia var and use it to have each question have a correct answer and display in the score div how many they got right at the end of the countdown. (My attempt at this is down at the bottom under Check awnsers in my JS) I hope that clears things up. @hallleron

Answer (score 0):

Move your score div outside of the question div:

```
<div id="score"></div>
<div id="questions"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Thought I did do that but upon a second look I did not I feel dumb now.

Comment: You're welcome :) maybe you can try to accept answer using the green checkmark on the left seeing as you are a new user.